# Why doesnt this reverse all the way?

Tags: python-2.7, list

I am doing another exam question and the snipped of code is given as the following:

```
def reverse(a):
   i=0
   while i < len(a):
       j = len(a) - 1
       tmp = a[i]
       a[j] = tmp
       a[i] = a[j]
       i = i +1

a = sys.argv
reverse(a)

print " ".join(a)
```

One of the questions asked is that you find the 5 errors. I have found 3 of the 5 but when I am trying to find the last two but my code does not fully sort the list.
Example if you did "1", "2", "3" it would print "3", "1", "2"

My edits to the above code:

```
import sys #error 1
def reverse(a):
   i = 0
   while i < len(a):
       j = len(a[i])-1 #error 2
       tmp = a[i] #I know its either this one or the two below...
       a[i] = a[j]
       a[j] = tmp
       i = i +1

a = sys.argv[1:]# error 3
reverse(a)

print " ".join(a)
```

I cannot use any builtin functions from python such as ".sort()"

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I assume the indentation is one of the bugs ;D

Comment: Apologies, indentation is fixed but it still doesnt finish sorting.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Why doesnt the code finish sorting if you did python "scriptname here" 1 2 3 4 5  that will print 5 1 2 3 4

Comment: From the command line python "scriptname" 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: `len(a[i])` would always be `1` for this input since your items are one-charactered strings.

Comment: When I made that change it and used  1 2 3 4 5  as a test case it printed 5 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reverse():
    i = 0
    while i < int(len(a) / 2):
        j = len(a) - 1 - i
        tmp = a[i] 
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = tmp
        i = i + 1
```

Reverse algorithm should do something like, swap 1-5, 2-4 then stop.

For 5 element input, you only need to do 2 swaps. Also `j` should move backward as `i` moves forward while you are iterating over input.

Since you are not returning anything from method and modify global `a`, you don't need the parameter.

BTW, in Python, instead of using `tmp` variable, you can use to swap elements.

```
a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was losing my mind trying to figure this out.